# mysql merge two columns into timestamp

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a mysql table that looks like so:

```
date        time
2009-07-31  02:30
2009-07-31  02:45
2009-07-31  03:00
```

'`date`' column is a `date` field and '`time`' column is a `text` field.

I would like to, using mysql only, merge these into a third column, '`datetime`' which is a `timestamp` field.

So the end result would look like this:

```
date        time     datetime
2009-07-31  02:30    2009-07-31 02:30
2009-07-31  02:45    2009-07-31 02:45
2009-07-31  03:00    2009-07-31 03:00
```

Not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy...

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN `datetime` timestamp;

UPDATE yourTable SET `datetime` = CONCAT(`date`, '  ', `time`);
```

Although I might add that reserved keywords like `date`, `time` and `datetime` are not good column names.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does have some 'loose type' behavior, so you can merge them as strings, and set the resulting string to the date-time column.

```
update `my_table` set `datetime`=concat(`date`, ' ', `time`);
```

Not all of the back-ticks are needed, but used to clarify the query.